# Creating shared memory in C

Tags: c, linux, posix, shared-memory

I created following method in C to create a shared memory segment to store counter value. But I can't store data in this segment.When I try to print the value of the counter it gives me a garbage value.Whats wrong with this code?

```
CreateCounter()
{
  key = ftok(".",'B');
  shmCntid = shmget(key,COUNTER_SIZE,IPC_CREAT|0666);

  if(shmCntid == -1 )
  {
    perror("shmget");
    exit(1);
  }

  else
  {
    printf("Creating new Sahred memory sement\n");
    cntPtr = shmat(shmCntid,0,0);
    if(cntPtr == -1 )
    {
      perror("shmat");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

This method is called inside the main method as follows.

```
   int *cntPtr;
   int rowCnt;
   sem_t s;
   sem_t c;
   sem_t r; 
  int main(int argc, int *argv[])
    {
      int pid, pid2, pid3, i;
      CreateBuf1();
      CreateBuf2();
      CreateCounter();
      GetInput(argv[1],*buf1Ptr);
      sem_init(&c, 0, 1);
      sem_init(&r, 0, 1);
      sem_init(&s, 0, 1);

      for( i = 0 ; i < 9; i++)
      {
        pid = fork();

        if(pid < 0)
        {
          printf("Fork error !\n");
        }

        else if (pid == 0)
        break;

      }



      if(pid < 0)
      {
        printf("Fork error !\n");
      }
      else if (pid == 0)
      {
        sem_wait(&r);
        Grp1 (i,i);
        cntPtr+=rowCnt;
        sleep(1);
        sem_post(&r);
        sem_post(&c);
        exit(0);
      }
      else
      {
        wait(NULL);
      }
      pid2 = fork();
      if(pid2 < 0)
      {
        printf("Fork error !\n");
      }

      else if (pid2 == 0)
      {
        sem_wait(&c);
        Grp2(9);
        cntPtr+=colCnt;
        sleep(1);
        sem_post(&c);
        exit(0);
      }
      else
      {
        wait(NULL);
      }

    // This space is to print the values..............

      shmctl(shmBuf1id,IPC_RMID,0);
      shmctl(shmBuf2id,IPC_RMID,0);
      shmctl(shmCntid,IPC_RMID,0);


    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried passing an absolute path instead of `"."`?

Comment: I don't immediately see an error in the code presented, other than the fact that the function's return type has been clipped off.  Please expand the code to present a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @KeineLust, to the best of my knowledge, it is not required to use an absolute pathname with `ftok()`.  In any event, if there were a problem with creating or attaching the shared memory segment then I would expect it to be caught by the OP's error checks.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the return type is void. This is created as a seperate method just to improve the readability of the main method.

Comment: @dolittele, the point of my first comment is that the error very likely arises from some part of your program other than what you have presented.  Adding the function return type is not nearly enough to create an MCVE.  Follow the link I provided if you are uncertain what is actually needed.

Comment: In fact, @dolittele, I took your exact code, built a simple program around it that writes to and reads from the shared memory segment, and tested it.  I saw no sign of misbehavior.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  I updated the queston.

Comment: Expressions such as this: `cntPtr+=rowCnt` increment the *pointer*, not the contents of the (shared) memory to which it points.  You want `*cntPtr+=rowCnt`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Can you please explain me how to initialize an integer variable inside the shared memory ?

Comment: @dolittele, there is nothing different about accessing shared memory via a pointer than accessing unshared memory via a pointer.  It can be easy to flub pointer usage, but if you don't understand pointer usage at all then shared memory is not the place for you to start.  Note in particular that you do not have an integer *variable* inside the shared memory.  Rather, you have a pointer to `int` (the pointer itself in unshared memory), and the space it is pointing to happens to be shared memory.  The shared bytes do not constitute a variable, they constitute the representation of a *value*.